# Gettting Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1012 ios & kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork error -1012

Tags: ios

while trying to pull data from server using "GET" sometimes I can access data from server but most of the time I getting  Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1012

```
     NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:20.0f];


[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
[request setHTTPShouldHandleCookies:NO];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request setValue:token forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-Auth-Token"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];



    NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];

    [NSURLConnection
     sendAsynchronousRequest:request
     queue:queue
     completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response,
                         NSData *data,
                         NSError *error) {
         if ([data length] >0 && error == nil){
             dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                 [self loadData:data];
             });
         }
         else if ([data length] == 0 && error == nil){
             [HUD hideUIBlockingIndicator];
             [CommonModule showAlert:APP_NAME :@" Unable to connect to the server! "];

             NSLog(@"Empty Response, not sure why?");
         }
         else if (error != nil){

             [HUD hideUIBlockingIndicator];
             [CommonModule showAlert:APP_NAME :@" Unable to connect to the server! "];
             NSLog(@"Not again, what is the error = %@", error);
         }
     }];
```

Comment: Check the server's SSL certificate. It could be invalid.

Comment: -1012 is `kCFURLErrorUserCancelledAuthentication`. You get that if authentication failed for some reason. Is your server configured to require authentication?

Comment: no just I adding user token as header which I got while login

Comment: I am not using https